# "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in angular 2 using @input

Tags: angular, typescript

I think I am doing everything right here.

Although the browser console shows the error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined":

[image]

My media.component.ts looks like following:

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'my-media-component',
templateUrl: `./app/media.component.html`,
styleUrls: [`./app/media.component.css`]
})
export class MediaAppComponent{
@Input() mediaItem;

onDelete(){
 console.log('deleting....');
}
}
```

My app.component.ts looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: `./app/app.component.html`,
 })
export class AppComponent  {
 firstMediaItem={
 name: 'sahil'
};
}
```

app.component.html looks like:

```
its, working
 <my-media-component [mediaItem]="firstMediaItem"></my-media-component>
```

media.component.html looks like:

```
<h1>{{mediaItem.name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the safe-navigation operator to guard agains `mediaItem` not yet being set when Angular tries to resolve the binding:

```
<h1>{{mediaItem?.name}}</h1>
```

**Update**

In your Plunker you have `MediaAppComponent` listed in `@NgModule({ bootstrap: [App, MediaAppComponent]})` but this component shouldn't be there if it is used as a normal component. Only root components should be listed there.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Nb3H9sHMuyjHPLEcR1s?p=preview)

Comment: It removes the errors from the console , yet purpose to display the name is not resolved...how can i view my name on browser

Comment: If you pass the value to `@Input() mediaItem` like  `[mediaItem]="'firstMediaItem'", then you pass a string, that doesn't have a `name` property. Therefore it's expected that you won't get anything shown.

Comment: I changed it to : [mediaItem]="firstMediaItem"    , still its unable to get mediaItem as an object ..                My browser Console shows :          `<my-media-component _nghost-vax-1="" ng-reflect-media-item="[object Object]" ng-version="2.4.6">
<h1 _ngcontent-vax-1=""></h1>
</my-media-component>`           ............  The <h1> tag remains empty ?!!!!

Comment: Agree with Günter Zöchbauer, the problem definately lies not in the piece of code you mentioned.

Comment: Yes i think , I did everything right here...M really stuck in what's the problem ????????

Comment: What do you get for `<h1>{{mediaItem}}</h1>` or `<h1>{{mediaItem | json}}</h1>`?

Comment: when I print : 
`<h1>{{ mediaItem }}</h1>
<h1>{{ mediaItem | json }}</h1>`

The values in <h1> Tag is empty. And Nothing gets Printed on the browser

Comment: Try reproducing in a Plunker. The `new` button provides an ready-to-use Angular2 template.

Comment: That's great. This way I can reproduce and investigate directly in the running project. You just would need to share the Plunker link ;-)

Comment: Thanks, the Plunker helped a lot. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotes "'firstMediaItem'"
just  `<my-media-component [mediaItem]="firstMediaItem"></my-media-component>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I did but nothing happened...now when i view the source in browser it shows :                                                                    `<my-media-component _nghost-cjq-1="" ng-reflect-media-item="[object Object]" ng-version="2.4.6">
<h1 _ngcontent-cjq-1=""></h1>
</my-media-component>`

Answer (score 1):

use elvis operator `?` instead

```
<h1>{{mediaItem?.name}}</h1>
```

this will prevent angualr to thorw any error if data is not present, and allow data to display asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Change it

```
[mediaItem]="'firstMediaItem'" ---> [mediaItem]="firstMediaItem"
```

After use like

```
<h1 *ngIf="mediaItem">{{mediaItem.name}}</h1>
```

Comment: Already Did that....Still error remains the same....
Refer the comments on Günter Zöchbauer's ANSWER