# Cannot read property 'list_tags' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have the model `Url`:

```
export class Url {
    author: String;
    description: String;
    list_tags: [{
        name: String
    }];
    count_click: Number;
    full_url: String;
    short_url: String;
    date: String;
    time: String;
}
```

From server side I get the data about url by id in `info-url.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Url } from '../shared/models/url.model';
import { UrlService } from '../shared/services/url.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-url',
  templateUrl: 'info-url.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['info-url.component.scss']
})
export class InfoUrlComponent implements OnInit {

  url: Url;
  edit: boolean = false;

  constructor(
      private urlService: UrlService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.urlService.getUrlById(id).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.url = data.url;
          this.edit = data.edit;
        }
    )
  }

}
```

Got data I output in `info-url.component.html`:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Little info about url</h1>
  <div class="url">
    <p>Full url: {{url.full_url}}</p>
    <p>Shortener-url: {{url.short_url}}</p>
    <div class="description">
      <h3>Little description:</h3>
      <p>{{url.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tags">
      <div *ngFor="let tag of url.list_tags">
        <a>{{tag.name}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="count">
      <p>{{url.count_click}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="date-time">
      <p>Date: {{url.date}}</p>
      <p>Url: {{url.time}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
      <p>Created by: <a>{{url.author}}</a></p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="edit">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In console output the next errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'list_tags' of undefined
    at Object.View_InfoUrlComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (InfoUrlComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13106)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12288)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12651)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12583)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12294)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12651)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12609)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12289)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12651)
```

Need to see 11th line in which `*ngFor` directive executes .

I could not understand why errors has in the template.
Please, help me.

Comment: May be, but I think that in future my question and answers will be help anybody also. If you didn't agree I want to know your reason

Comment: Excuse me, is your comment directed to me Alexey? If so, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: My comment was directed to you. I want to say that I disagree with yours first post.  P.S. Excuse me, for my skill English because I beginning.

Comment: You are totally entitled to your opinion. We are just here to avoid posting duplicate questions, and if they are duplicate, we should mark them as duplicates. There is lots of this same question on SO, so I suggest you to make a thorough search before posting a question. If you just google your title, you find many questions, here's a couple more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268832/cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined-in-angular-2-using-input and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined all with the same issue :)

Comment: I agree with your opinion. Excuse me. I think that in future I will not duplicate questions anymore in the stackoverflow.

Comment: No worries Alexey! BTW I haven't made the rules here, I just try to follow them :) Glad you got your answer though :) Have a nice day and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url` is not defined initially, it will be after `ngOnInit` is triggered.

this should fix it

```
*ngFor="let tag of url?.list_tags"
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your answer on my question very help to me.

Comment: Great, then please mark my answer as the solution to your question, thanks

Comment: It's ok. I don't see any problem :)